# What is <-- in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I came across below snippet. It outputs to  `4 3 2 1`

I never came across `<--` in Java.

Is `<--`  an operator that makes the value of var1 to var2?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int var1 = 5, var2 = 0;
        while (var2 <-- var1) {
            System.out.print(" " + var1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's var2 < (--var1), where -- is prefixed decrementation

Comment: What truly awful, misleading code. Did the person writing it actively dislike the people who would have to maintain it? *(Good question, btw.)*

Comment: Upvoting indicates _This question shows research effort[...]_ except this question doesn't show that in my opinion. The primary source for this information should be the Java language specification. Also, a search here on SO would likely have found the duplicates. So `-1`

Comment: after reading question, I thought Java has really introduced something interesting...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`<--` is  not a new Java operator (even though it may look like it), but there are 2 normal operators: `<` and `--`

`while (var2 <-- var1)` is the same as `while(var2 < (--var1))`, which can be translated to plain english as:

1. decrement the `var1` variable ( `--var` is a prefix decrementation, ie. decrement the variable before condition validation)
2. Validate the condition `var2 < var1`

Answer (score 8):

`<--` There is no such operator in java.

It is `var2 < (--var1)` A relational + decrement operator.